# Como arreglar un bug con active navbar bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap, navbar

Creando mi navbar en bootstrap usando react, me tope con este pequeño error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen aparece que Home esta activo pero yo en en codigo no lo tengo activo, es mas work deberia ser el que este activo, no home como se muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando entro al inspector de elementos esto es lo que me aparece, y en mi codigo esto es lo que tengo escrito:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav id="contentNavBar" className="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div className='container-lg'>
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item"><a className='nav-link' href='#home'>Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a className='nav-link active' href='#Work'>Work</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class='container' data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#contentNavBar" data-bs-offset="0" tabindex="0">
        <div id='home'>
          <Home/>
        </div>
        <div id='about'>
          <About/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

como se puede notar tengo activado el tag de work no el de home, no entiendo muy bien que esta pasando, saben de alguna forma de arreglarlo?

Comment: No se si tendra demasiado que ver, no uso reactjs, pero si lo pongo todo como `class=` en lugar de `className` funciona:  https://jsfiddle.net/1x89u4eq/ ... aparte de eso, si en reactjs es imperativo usar `className` en lugar de `class` te aviso que tienes algunos `class=` en tu código.

Comment: Porqué no usas NavLink? Si lo importas, solo bastaría con añadir `activeClassName="active"`. Otra opción sería con hooks y `useLocation`

Answer (score 0):

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link
Usa React Router v6 y aplica la propiedad end al final de la etiqueta NavLink que usas para el home:

```
<NavLink
                            key={'home'}
                            className={({ isActive }) => `nav-link ${isActive ? 'active' : ''}`}
                            to="/" end>
                            Home
                        </NavLink>
```